# How can I speed up gd imagepng

Tags: php, gd

I am using gd library to generate images. The process is slow, so when I open the image during the saving process I get blank screen. How can I avoid that?

It takes ~0.4 sec to save the image, if you  refresh the image in that time you will get blank screen.

The script is slow it takes 6 sec to generate image, during which you will see the old image.

Comment: even if you save image in less than 1ms you may face the same problem. because the refresh can hit the server at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid "blank screen" caused by the saving process, you can save an image as a new file (for example `hi_finished.png`) and after saving, rename it as `hi.png`.